# Add a calender control in knockout editable grid

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to add a calender control in knockout editable grid I have added a calender in my needed Column when the grid rendered the first row added was attached with the calender but all the dynamically added rows I add (generated with the same id) not attached with the Calender.

So what should i do ?

```
<td><input type="text" id="Calender" class='span11 required' data-bind="value: Date" /></td>
```

i'm using the following example:

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/7RDc3/

Answer (score 0):

you have to do a date custom binding, if you dont want to write your own, there is a good datepicker [here](http://makingsense.github.io/moment-datepicker/) that is ready to work with ko. docs are not very clear but just see source code and you will there is all you need.

this is how you use it:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm borderless-control" placeholder="Seleccione Fecha"
                               data-bind="datepicker: $data.date, datepickerOptions: { format: 'LL' }" />
```

You will need [moment js](http://momentjs.com/) too wich is a really good library to work with dates

hope it helps!

Comment: I would like to ask what is $data in data-bind should i replace it with my model or what, if there is a full Example or adding your code to jsfiddle i will be greatful